# Using SwiftyJSON with Swift3

Tags: swift3, cocoapods, swifty-json

How do I use SwiftyJSON with Swift3? I've installed the pod.

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git', :branch => 'swift3'
```

But it throws a lot of errors using Xcode 8 GM.

Can someone help me install it properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SwiftyJSON [now supports Swift 3](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/647).

`pod 'SwiftyJSON', '3.0.0'`

Answer (score 27):

**Update:** as Marcus notes, SwiftyJSON now supports Swift 3. In order to get bug fixes, I recommend *not* pinning yourself to 3.0.0, but rather:

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '>= 3.0.0'
```

…or if you don’t want to accidentally pick up whatever API-breaking changes may arrive in 4.x:

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 3.0'
```

---

**[Old answer]** There is an actively maintained fork that works:

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON', git: 'https://github.com/BaiduHiDeviOS/SwiftyJSON.git', branch: 'swift3'
```

Hopefully the project maintainers merge it. Until then, you can just use the fork.

Comment: You're awesome, my lorde. Thank you very much

Comment: Trying to build via Carthage didn't work for me, but I pulled this code on its own from their Github, and it works fine! Thank you for posting this!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I had a trouble for days. And this solve the issue for me.

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '3.1.4'
```

Comment: There's no need to post a new answer every time the version changes. Existing answers already show how to update the repository version.